# Expo go not connecting after QR code scanning

Tags: expo

When I want to test my app using expo go I get an error, although I have good internet connection on laptop and mobile, Wi-Fi Network is the same. What could be an issue?
Phone is Huawei mate 20 pro [image]

Comment: see: https://docs.expo.io/get-started/create-a-new-app/#opening-the-app-on-your-phonetablet - also Martin's suggestion below. you can use the "Tunnel" connection type if you're not sure how to configure your network to resolve this

Comment: I add exact same problem after have run a tunnel with ngrok, and switched from lan to local, and finally expo connected to the app and rebuilt it

Comment: Update as happening again after a month or so, but this time as I could not build the web due to some old library that didn't had correct polyfill I was stuck, even did not worked the internal ngrok that now expo has. What did "triggered" a new build, thus connecting the device is to switch connection and back to privious(or simply try another common connection that is not hotpost from phone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same problem after updating to the expo-cli. Turned out it was a firewall issue.

I also had to change my home network to be 'private'

Comment: Hello, Thanks for information. I have just set network to private. Can You please share more precisely what have You changed in Your firewall ? What kind of parameters I should search to change ? Thanks !

Comment: In Windows 10, open Settings and go to "Network & Internet." Then, if you use a Wi-Fi network, go to Wi-Fi, click or tap the name of the network you are connected to, and then change the network profile to Private or Public, depending on what you need.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you are on the same Wi-Fi network on your computer and your device.
If it still doesn't work, it may be due to the router configuration.

If any one have this problem and want an easy fix run `expo start --tunnel`

from the documentations:

> Using the "Tunnel" connection type will make app reloads considerably slower than on "LAN" or "Local", so it's best to avoid tunnel when possible. You may want to install a simulator/emulator to speed up development if "Tunnel" is required for accessing your machine from another device on your network

Answer (score 0):

i dont this it is about the Commnd and Network

Below QR code please have a Look

```
 › Metro waiting on exp+native-apps://expo-development-client/?url=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.0.103%3A8081
› Scan the QR code above to open the project in a development build. Learn more: https://expo.fyi/start

› Web is waiting on http://localhost:8081

› Using development build
› Press s │ switch to Expo Go

› Press a │ open Android
› Press w │ open web

› Press j │ open debugger
› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu
› Press o │ open project code in your editor

› Press ? │ show all commands
```

These Lines will Help

```
Press s │ switch to Expo Go
```

i had this Issue

if you are Facing more issue Try run the Tunnel

```
expo start --tunnel
```

or

```
yarn start --tunnel
```

This Should be Enough.....